# Facebook share using graph api photos with text not woking

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API to share the multiple photos with text, i am using "public_actions" to share the photos and text in post but i am facing this error

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800045da30 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}}

Can any one help me out with this error ? 
I am following this [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads#publishing-a-multi-photo-story)

**Here's my code for this**

```
 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] != nil) {

    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
           FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos"
                                                  parameters:@{ @"url": exercise.exerciseImageUrl,@"caption": @"test messages",@"published": @"false",}
                                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                        // Insert your code here

                        NSLog(@"%@",result);

                        if ([result objectForKey:@"id"] != nil) {
                            //[idArray addObject:[result objectForKey:@"id"]];
                            [dict1 setObject:[result objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"media_fbid"];
                        }


                        if (arrayTotalImages.count == dict1.count) {
                            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                            [dict setObject:dict1 forKey:@"attached_media[0]"]; // add 5 images 
                            [dict setObject:@"Test" forKey:@"message"];

                            FBSDKGraphRequest *request1 = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                                           initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                                           parameters:dict
                                                           HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                            [request1 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                // Insert your code here

                                NSLog(@"%@",result);

                            }];
                        }

                    }];

    }
}
```